# Python 3.x ctypes c_wchar_p return is different from official documentation example

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

#### Python Version

Python 3.5.2

#### Issue

I found that the [c_wchar_p](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_wchar_p) and [c_char_p](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p) return results behaves different from what it is based on ctypes doc. From the ctypes doc of Python 3.5:

```
>>> c_wchar_p("Hello, World")
c_wchar_p('Hello, World')
```

It return the ctypes string. But my results of execute the same cmd in Python3.5 console:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_wchar_p("Hello, World")
c_wchar_p(1374004842736)
>>> c_wchar_p("Hello, World")
c_wchar_p(1374004841680)
>>> c_wchar_p("Hello, World")
c_wchar_p(1374004842736)
```

So seems like the orignial string part replaced by memory address. Digged in more, and found out if it is Python 2.x, then the return shows the string like the Python 3.5 ctypes doc shows. But in Python 3.x, it always return these numbers. Checked on multiple PCs, all seen the same thing. And understood the part that, we can use .value to return the original string. Same thing observed on create_string_buffer() and create_unicode_buffer(). Meanwhile, for other data types like c_int(), c_bool, c_void_p etc., not see this.

#### Question

- Can anyone provide a explaination about this behavior of ctypes?
- And is there any way to fix the Python3.x return resuls as the same as what is doc wrote?

Thanks a lot in advance~

Comment: I tried this with python 3.4.3 on linux mint and it worked like the example.

Comment: Testing on http://python.org/shell matches your experience. I don't know whether the error is in the documentation or the implementation, but either way, it sounds like you should file a bug report.

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks, I tried on U14/Win10 with both Python2.7 and Python3.5, and both Python3.5 version show me the different result from the doc. Haven't roll back the try on 3.4 yet, but not sure why this happens...

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112, do you where I should file a bug on this?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/